# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-15

After migration in Wildfly15, I cannot run my tests using Arquillian. I get the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer." I have tried a lot of differnet combinations in versions but not seemed to solve the problem. Any ideas on this?

the pom.xml file contains:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <!-- ShrinkWrap -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ShrinkWrap Resolver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ShrinkWrap Descriptors -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Beta3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
<profile>
            
            <id>wildfly-managed</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            
            <properties>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </properties>
            
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
                    <version>12.0.3.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
...
</profile>
```